# For a given table give out the count for each row Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

if i have a table like this:

```
ID  | Name   | Payment
----------------------
101 | Victor | 10
103 | Andy   | 13
134 | Mai    | 2
156 | Chris  | 68
179 | Ryan   | 43
```

And I wanna have a query that gives out the following

```
[Count] | ID  | Name   | Payment
----------------------
1       | 101 | Victor | 10
2       | 103 | Andy   | 13
3       | 134 | Mai    | 2
4       | 156 | Chris  | 68
5       | 179 | Ryan   | 43
```

So it gives out the number of each row but I don't know how to do it ( am a beginner at SQL). Any tips?

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `row_number()`:

```
select row_number() over (order by id) as "Count",
       t.*
from t
order by "Count";
```

You should have both `order by`s to be sure the numbering on the rows is correct and the order of the rows in the result set is correct.

Answer (score 0):

use `dense_rank()`

```
select *,dense_rank() over(order by id) from t
```

or you could use `count()`

```
  select *,count(*) over(order by id) from t
```

Answer (score 0):

simple

```
select rownum, ID , Name, Payment from table
```